# Regex to match pattern only if a string is not present in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Stuck with finding a regex for a typical scenario. Not sure how this can be achieved in regex.

```
Regex ---> (?is)[^:]\/\/
Payload ---> Regexp,test//check//last://
Matches ---> t// and k//
```

Issue : I need to modify the above regex to ignore match for // only if the test string starts with "data:image"(as in below payload).

```
Payload ---> data:image/png;base64,test//check//last://
```

In this above case it should not match for my criteria (match for //) since the test string starts with "data:image"

Suggest a way to modify the above regex, so that we can handle this case.

Comment: Check if the string starts with the value first. Anyway, you cannot use a `(?<!^data:image.*)` since JS regex engine does not support infinite-width lookbehinds.

Comment: Do you need _all matches_ in every payload as output?

Comment: yes, i need to find all the pattern and then eliminate them. But i don't want to do this action only if the payload starts with "data:image"(I mean here in 2nd case, i don't want the pattern match to occur). Trying to achieve some sort of "not if then match"

Comment: How about something like: `/(?!data:image)(?:.*?)([^:]\/\/)/giy`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the regex to match your pattern `//` and the preceding character which shouldn't be `:`. And the matches should only be done if the test string does *not* start with `data:image`.

```
/(?!data:image)(?:.*?)([^:]\/\/)/giy
```

- `(?!data:image)` ensures that the string doesn't start with data:image
- `(?:.*?)` non-capturing non-greedy match
- `([^:]\/\/)` your match `//` and the preceding character which shouldn't be `:`
- `/y` to denote a sticky match so that it matches only from where a previous match ended. That way, for strings starting with `data:image` it won't match anything

```js
var regex = /(?!data:image)(?:.*?)([^:]\/\/)/giy

// This shouldn't match since test string starts with data:image
var payload = "data:image/png;base64,test//check//last://";
var match = regex.exec(payload);
console.log(match);

// This should find matches since payload doesn't start with data:image
var anotherpayload = "Regexp,test//check//last://";
match = regex.exec(anotherpayload);
while (match != null) {
  // Accessing group 1
  console.log(match[1])
  match = regex.exec(anotherpayload);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did work. But i didn't complete clarity on how it worked. Why exactly is (?:.*?) needed here and how it worked with sticky 'y' flag? Please provide more inputs or any doc link which i can refer.
Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. You can play around with these demo's: https://regex101.com/r/Fp7paW/1 and https://regex101.com/r/7UJVYD/1/. `(?:` denotes a non capturing group and `.*?` is just to to match any character (non-greedy). The `/y` sticky flag tells the engine to continue matching from where previous match ended. This is so that if the string starts with `data:image` then it doesn't match anything

Comment: It worked fine on the client side with the javascript engine. But on the server side, i'm using Java pattern class and on compile i'm getting below error. It's the same with java8. Any solution/alternative that you can suggest in order to get this working.

Exception on Pattern.compile(regExp) : java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 4
(?isy)(?!data:image)(?:.*?)([^:]//)